# How to fix Powershell from stripping double quotes in a file

Tags: powershell, docker

I define a variable in Windows powershell like this

```
1.$LFILE=cat license.json
2.echo $LFILE
   {
    "source": "ABCD LTD",
    "clientId": "EAL",
    "details": "Lenses",
    "key": "acfghkjhadasldas"
   }

3.docker run --rm -d -p 3030:3030 -e LICENSE=$LFILE landoop/kafka-lenses-dev:latest
```

After i run this when i look at the license file inside docker container it removes the double quotes.

When i check from inside the docker container this is what i see. if you see below the quotes are stripped off.

```
root@fast-data-dev / $ cat /var/run/lenses/license.conf
{
  source: ABCD LTD,
  clientId: EAL,
  details: Lenses,
  key: acfghkjhadasldas 
}

io.lenses.core.license.LicenseException: Can not read the license 
file:/var/run/lenses/license.conf
```

I tried to put $LFILE in single and double quotes.
I tried to put the file name directly in docker command like this. still no luck.

```
docker run --rm -d -p 3030:3030 -e LICENSE="'$(cat license.json)'" landoop/kafka-lenses-dev:latest
```

Comment: The JSON you post is invalid.

Comment: Use Jsonlint.com to fix your JSON first.  Secondly, you should be able to just run this:  `docker run --rm -d -p 3030:3030 -e LICENSE="'$(get-content .\license.json)'" landoop/kafka-lenses-dev:latest`

Comment: @Theo its a license file so i cannot post the entire file. I only posted a few words from the file. But i think you understand what i am asking. I tested in gitbash and it works fine.

Comment: Sure, but then at least enter some fake value for the `"details"` item and not post invalid json.

Comment: @FoxDeploy its still the same however it has single quote at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: Why do we think Powershell is stripping out the double quotes?

Comment: I think so because when i try the same using gitbash it works like a charm. when i use powershell i dont see double quotes around the the license file and UI wont come up.

Comment: I also tried this before passing the file                                              
      `dos2unix.exe license.json`
      `dos2unix: converting file license.json to Unix format...`

Comment: If you do need the double quotes in your license file just encase them in single ticks. For example the line with "source": "ABCD LTD", would change to '"source"': '"ABCD LTD"',. That will retain your double quotes.

Comment: @DBADon I tried enclosing it with single ticks but it still does not retain the double quotes. The output in the file is 'source':'ABCD LTD'

Answer (score 0):

Using the "cat" command alone will return an Object[]. I am assuming docker is looking for a string. To get a string use one of the following.

```
$LFILE = Get-Content license.json -Raw
```

or

```
$LFILE = cat license.json -Raw
```

since you are running Kafka I looked up the licensing config for that. Below is what they said:

> In order to run, Lenses requires a license file which can be obtained
>   from us. Once you have received your license, store it in a file (
>   i.e. license.file) and update the configuration to point to it. Make
>   sure the configuration value contains the full file path.

```
# License file allowing connecting to up to N brokers
lenses.license.file="license.json"
```

According to your current docker command you are trying to set an environment variable for the license. When, it seems, you need to put a file in the container and then set the lenses.license.file="full/license/file/path/license.json"

It seems like you need to run something like below, but it is only looking for the key, not the entire file.

```
docker run -p 3030:3030 -e EULA="CHECK_YOUR_EMAIL_FOR_KEY" \ --name=lenses-dev landoop/kafka-lenses-dev
```

[Lenses Documentation v2.3](https://docs.lenses.io/dev/lenses-box/)

Comment: So it is still removing your quotes @Des

Comment: @Des I updated my answer. I don't think the problem is PowerShell removing quotes. It seems that you may be putting your license information in the wrong place, and the reason it keeps saying that it cannot read the license file is because it is set up wrong.

Comment: I dont think i am putting it in wrong place. If what you say is correct then there should not be anything in that directory or an error stating no file found. I ssh into the container and see it has picked up the license file without quotes. It works well in gitbash.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the formatting needs of a Docker license but if you need the double quotes in there, why not shortcut what you have and just explicitly create the variable the way you need it?

```
$LFILE = '{
    "source": "ABCD LTD",
    "clientId": "EAL",
    "details": "Lenses",
    "key": "acfghkjhadasldas"
   }'
```

-OR SHOULD IT BE-

```
$LFILE = '"source": "ABCD LTD",
    "clientId": "EAL",
    "details": "Lenses",
    "key": "acfghkjhadasldas"'
```

- THEN -

```
## TEST AND ENSURE THE VARIABLE IS FORMATTED CORRECTLY ##
$LFILE

## NOW ADD IT TO YOUR COMMAND AND EXECUTE ##
docker run --rm -d -p 3030:3030 -e LICENSE=$LFILE landoop/kafka-lenses-dev:latest
```